# Is it possible to add "dsafe_mode=Off" inside a php file?

Tags: php

I'm running a script that needs `dsafe_mode=Off`.

I can run this script in terminal using php -`dsafe_mode=Off /usr/src`.

But I want to run it over the web, **Is it possible to add `dsafe_mode=Off` inside the code ?**

Something like:

```
<?php -dsafe_mode=Off
....SCRIPT.....
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

That would moot the whole reason of why `safe_mode` was introduced in the first place. `safe_mode` has also been removed from PHP 5.4. You'll have to change it in php.ini or from the context when the script is executed.

Comment: the thing is, safe_mode is already 0, but it still not working.

Comment: You probably want to confirm with `phpinfo()` or `ini_get()` that the value has actually been changed, and not something you just believe has been done.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.

`safe_mode`'s **[changeable level](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php)** is `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`, which means you could change this setting only in **php.ini** or **httpd.conf**.

Comment: I already set `SAFE_MODE = OFF` but it still wont work...  `"shell_exec(): Cannot execute using backquotes in Safe Mode"`